# How do I use the web colour editor in my own property grid?

Tags: .net, propertygrid

I have a custom configuration tool for an application that uses the .Net `PropertyGrid` control.

The classes underneath have `Color` properties that are edited in the grid. If I don't decorate the attributes at all I get a drop down colour picker that lets me choose Windows system colours.

However this is for a web site, so I want hexadecimal colour codes. I can specify these with a type converter:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(WebColorConverter))]
public Color Background { ...
```

This fixes the input from RGB to hex, but the drop down stays as a list of Windows system colours - like this:

[image: What I have]

In Visual Studio when dealing with web controls I get a modal pop up with a hexagonal colour selector instead.

[image: What I want]

I want to get the modal web colour editor rather than the windows forms variant.

However, I looked at `System.Web.UI.WebControls` colour properties and they just specify the `TypeConverter` - they don't specify a `UITypeEditor`.

Anyone know how to get the same editor as the web controls?